# In Hopscotch, how do you find the senders of a message?

Tags: newspeak

In Newspeak's IDE, Hopscotch, what is the equivalent to Smalltalk's alt-n, which shows you all senders of a message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found out:

> [Alt-m and Alt-n are residual Squeak/Morphic behavior and doesn't work in Windows native mode. Instead you can use the little icon which looks like a speech bubble.](http://forums.newspeaklanguage.org/index.php?topic=20.0)